# Run-time error '21' (VBA + Selenium+Chrome)

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code is working well but after running several times it stuck with Run-time error '21'.

It cannot open webdriver with run-time error '21': as attached picture.

'bot. start "Chrome" which is the code that has the error.

Chrome version: 83.0.4103.97

Selenium: SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcO8q.jpg)

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim ele As WebElement
Dim picEle As WebElement
Dim awbaLI As WebElements
Dim AWB As List


bot.Start "Chrome"

bot.Get "https://google.com"
```

Comment: If i restart computer, it works well again for a while but the error comes up later...

Comment: Ensure that the chrome version and chromedriver versions are in sync and that the folder containing the chromedriver .exe is on the environmental path. https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/196

Comment: Chrome driver version is right one and it works well.. Problem is that this error occurs after running script several times.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you Port (62982, according to your provided screenshot) is still in use and thus cannot be reused.

You must also close to bot instance in order to release the port again (this also explains why it works again when you restart your PC (because then all the ports are released automatically)
In this case this can be done by calling `bot.Quit` at the very end of your bot usage / script!

Comment: Hello Schutt, thank you so much for your advise! I'll check with it and get back to you !

Comment: I worked with bot.quit but it didn't work well.. Run-time error '21' came out again. Is there any way to extend the run-time for webdriver opening in selenium? I guess it was due to slow processing between excel file and VBA...When i start the script with button on excel, this error occurs more often.. However, if  i start with VBA application directly error comes up less... is there any way to prevent this by allowing extended run-time?

Comment: Plus, if i open chrome manually and do bot.start "chrome" at the same time it works...even after run-time error '21'... so i don't understand this... this is temporary fix and if i do it again without manual opening of chrome, i cannot open webdriver with selenium again... there must be some root cause but i don't now how to fix it..